# Difference Between of different types of taskscheduler implements classes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am working on project where task scheduling is going to use and I have confusion that which task scheduler implements class is use for me where `n` number of requests will arrive in my API and process the task in given scheduling time.

List of class are:

1. concurrent task scheduling
2. thread pool task scheduling
3. others

Comment: Have already read [the spring framework docs on task scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)? Could you explain a bit more what exactly is unclear to you about the provided Scheduler implementations?

Comment: Read the Spring Boot Documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-task-execution-scheduling There is also Quartz https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-quartz